# Java abstract method object creation is bad?

Tags: java, object, libgdx, jvm, lwjgl

I am programming a game *for years now* but I have a question about how I programmed things up.

So imagine you have a gun class for a game, guns can have many sprites, sounds, casings, projectiles, parameters, etc. So then I just need to create another class extending this gun class and fill my abstract methods up with what I need that particular gun to do.

So I made an abstract class to handle all of the internal code of the gun, if it shoots, if it needs bolt action and how long it has to wait, when to play the fire sound, etc. So basically the main gun class calls for the actual gun class (that is filled with abstract methods) for these parameters.

So my question is, if I am calling these abstract methods over and over again as needed throughout the code is it bad to have the following?

```
@Override
protected String getName() {
    //This should be ok
    return "Winchester";
}

@Override
protected boolean isBoltAction() {

    //This should be ok
    return false;
}

@Override
protected float getBoltActionTime() {

    //This should be ok
    return 0.5f;
}

@Override
protected Vector2 getPosOffset() {
    //problem? or not?
    return new Vector2(3,0);
}
```

If I call getPosOffset which I need it to be an Vector2 object for simplicity, the object itself shouldn't be too much expensive but would this create problems down the line? I ask because afaik even though the object itself doesn't change and is preset it is creating a new one everytime I call this method without really needing to, I could load a list and put everything there neatly without creating additional objects but that could make my abstract class kinda useless atleast for these methods. Is it bad to do this and should I change this? I've tried to see how many nanoseconds it takes if I load it up in a field vs this way and I saw no significant expense on time.

The game is running smoothly though but I am just not sure if my ocd is acting up or there is something problematic here.

**UPDATE:**

```
protected void update() {
    //get position of player
    pos.x = (float) (LevelManager.getPlayer().getPos().x);
    pos.y = (float) (LevelManager.getPlayer().getPos().y);

    //Tweener stuff to animate the recoil
    posOffset.x = recoilTweener.tick();
    
    //Fire time check
    if (timePassed >= this.salvoDelay) {
        //fire only if:
        //if its automatic then allow it
        //And
        //if not needsBoltAction and we haven't "reloaded" the boltaction, these are Firearm fields not properties
        //and
        //if mouse left button is pressed
        if (((this.automatic || !shooted) && (!needsBoltAction && !boltActionActive)) && Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)) {
            //prevents hold firing for non automatic weapons
            shooted = true;
            //Tells us that we should fire
            firing = true;
        } else if (!Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)) {
            //If the left mouse button isn't held lets reset
            shooted = false;
        }
    } else {
        //if time hasn't passed lets wait
        timePassed += Math.min(Gameloop.getFrameTime(), this.salvoDelay);
    }

    //If we can fire and it was triggered above
    if (firing) {
        //Set time for salvo, in the sense each salvo shoots x projectiles within a set amount of time in between
        timePassed += Math.min(Gameloop.getFrameTime(), this.salvoDelay + this.shotsPerSalvo * this.shotDelay);
        //if we have shots to fire
        //and
        //if timepassed is bigger than the current shot * shotDelay
        if (this.shotsPerSalvo > shotsFired && timePassed - this.salvoDelay >= shotsFired * this.shotDelay) {
            if (this.shotDelay == 0) {
                //Create projectile and set it up
                createProjectile(this.shotsPerSalvo);
                //Since we have 0 shotDelay we set this to false and reset the gun
                firing = false;
                shotsFired = 0;
                timePassed = 0;
                //"Ask" properties if we need boltAction
                needsBoltAction = this.boltAction;
            } else {
                //Create each individual shot according to the time
                createProjectile(1);
                //Increase shotsFired for calculations
                shotsFired++;
            }
        //If shotsFired reached the shotsPerSalvo, again each salvo has x shots to be fired in an instant (example shotguns, glocks in burst mode)
        } else if (shotsFired >= this.shotsPerSalvo) {
            //Reset weapon
            firing = false;
            shotsFired = 0;
            timePassed = 0;
            //"Ask" properties if we need boltAction
            needsBoltAction = this.boltAction;
        }
    }

    //BoltAction logic
    //If needsBoltAction was triggered and we press R "reload" and wait (boltActionTime)
    if (needsBoltAction && Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.R)) {
        //Doing boltaction
        boltActionActive = true;
        //We dont need to press R again
        needsBoltAction = false;
    }

    //We are doing the boltAction and not firing the gun
    if (boltActionActive && !firing) {
        //Add time
        //Remember that timePassed was reset when all shots were fired on a salvo, in any situation
        timePassed += Math.min(Gameloop.getFrameTime(), this.boltActionTime);
        //If time was enough
        if (timePassed >= this.boltActionTime) {
            //We can shoot again since boltAction is done
            boltActionActive = false;
            timePassed = 0;
        }
    }

}

private void createProjectile(int amount) {

    if (amount <= 0) {
        Console.write(new Color(1,0,0,1),"Error: Projectile amount is invalid!");
    }

    if (getFireSoundFile() != null) {
        getFireSoundFile().play();
    }

    if (this.casing != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.casingsPerSalvo; i++) {
            ParticleManager.add(createCasing());
        }
    }

    recoilTweener.reset();

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        Projectile p = createProjectile();
        p.setup(LevelManager.getPlayer().getPos().x + (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(WeaponManager.angle)) * this.shotStartingPosOffset.x + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(WeaponManager.angle)) * this.shotStartingPosOffset.y), LevelManager.getPlayer().getPos().y + (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(WeaponManager.angle)) * this.shotStartingPosOffset.x + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(WeaponManager.angle)) * this.shotStartingPosOffset.y), WeaponManager.angle + Utils.getRandomFloat(this.spread,true));
        WeaponManager.addProjectile(p);
    }
}   
private Casing createCasing() {
    return new Casing(this.casing, this.pos);
}

private Projectile createProjectile() {
    return new Projectile(this.projectile);
}
```

At the moment I have the properties read as so:

```
    protected Firearm() {       
    loadParameters();
    //other stuff
}

/**
 * Loads all guns parameters from the abstract methods
 * This is to only load these methods only once
 */
private void loadParameters() {
    this.casing = getCasing();
    this.magazineDrop = getMagazineDrop();
    this.casingsPerSalvo = getCasingsPerSalvo();
    this.unlimitedAmmo = hasUnlimitedAmmo();
    this.projectile = getProjectile();  
    this.projectileDamage = getProjectileDamage();
    this.spread = getSpread();
    this.shotsPerSalvo = getShotsPerSalvo();
    this.salvoDelay = getSalvoDelay();
    this.shotDelay = getShotDelay();
    this.automatic = isAutomatic();
    this.fireSound = getFireSound();
    this.reloadSound = getReloadSound();
    this.name = getName();
    this.boltAction = isBoltAction();
    this.boltActionTime = getBoltActionTime();
    this.shotStartingPosOffset = getShotStartingPosOffset();
    this.recoilOffset = getRecoilOffset();      
}

/**
 * Gets bullet casing sprite
 */
protected abstract Casing getCasing();
protected Casing casing;

/**
 * Gets magazine object
 */
protected abstract Magazine getMagazineDrop();
protected Magazine magazineDrop;

/**
 * Number of casing drops per salvo
 */
protected abstract int getCasingsPerSalvo();
protected int casingsPerSalvo;

/**
 * If the weapon has unlimited ammo
 */
protected abstract boolean hasUnlimitedAmmo();
protected boolean unlimitedAmmo;

/**
 * Projectile texture path
 */
protected abstract Projectile getProjectile();
protected Projectile projectile;

/**
 * Projectile Damage
 */
protected abstract float getProjectileDamage();
protected float projectileDamage;

/**
 * Angle spread, angle added to each shot
 */
protected abstract float getSpread();
protected float spread;

/**
 * Shots fired per salvo
 */
protected abstract int getShotsPerSalvo();
protected int shotsPerSalvo;

/**
 * Not to be confused with getShotDelay
 * This is the delay per salvo (each salvo will fire a number of shots)
 */
protected abstract float getSalvoDelay();
protected float salvoDelay;

/**
 * Delay per shot on a salvo
 */
protected abstract float getShotDelay();
protected float shotDelay;

/**
 * If true then the pistol is automatic, if false the pistol is semi-automatic
 */
protected abstract boolean isAutomatic();
protected boolean automatic;

/**
 * If true then the pistol is automatic, if false the pistol is semi-automatic
 * Note: this should only return the name of the file+extension, the file will be looked up in the internal folder "sounds/sfx/weapons/fire"
 */
protected abstract String getFireSound();
protected String fireSound;

/**
 * If true then the pistol is automatic, if false the pistol is semi-automatic
 * Note: this should only return the name of the file+extension, the file will be looked up in the internal folder "sounds/sfx/weapons/fire"
 */
protected abstract String getReloadSound();
protected String reloadSound;

/**
 * Weapon's name
 */
protected abstract String getName();
protected String name;

/**
 * If true then player will need to press R to reload
 */
protected abstract boolean isBoltAction();
protected boolean boltAction;

/**
 * Time of bolt action
 */
protected abstract float getBoltActionTime();
protected float boltActionTime;

/**
 * Firearm's bullet starting position offset
 * Will automatically rotate angle
 */
protected abstract Vector2 getShotStartingPosOffset();
protected Vector2 shotStartingPosOffset;

/**
 * Firearm's recoil in units to be subtracted to the weapons default offset position
 * Will make the firearm go backwards and fowards with a tweener according to the units
 * I am putting a vector2 just incase I need the firearm to recoil in the y vector but I atm dont see any use
 */
protected abstract Vector2 getRecoilOffset();
protected Vector2 recoilOffset;
```

Just incase you need the properties:

```
    public class Winchester extends Firearm {

public Winchester() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String getSprite() {

    return "winchesterwh.png";
}

@Override
public String getSpriteDropped() {

    return null;
}

@Override
protected Casing getCasing() {

    return new Casing("sprites/weapons/casing/smallcasing.png", new Vector2(0,0));
}

@Override
protected Magazine getMagazineDrop() {

    return null;
}

@Override
protected int getCasingsPerSalvo() {

    return 1;
}

@Override
protected boolean hasUnlimitedAmmo() {

    return false;
}

@Override
protected Projectile getProjectile() {

    return new Projectile("sprites/weapons/projectiles/bullet.png", new Vector2(2,20), 50f, 0f, getProjectileDamage());
}

@Override
protected float getProjectileDamage() {
    return 10f;
}

@Override
protected float getSpread() {

    return 1f;
}

@Override
protected int getShotsPerSalvo() {

    return 5;
}

@Override
protected float getSalvoDelay() {

    return 0.25f;
}

@Override
protected float getShotDelay() {

    return 0.25f;
}

@Override
protected boolean isAutomatic() {

    return false;
}

@Override
protected String getFireSound() {

    return "sniperShot.ogg";
}

@Override
protected String getReloadSound() {

    return null;
}

@Override
protected String getName() {

    return "Winchester";
}

@Override
protected boolean isBoltAction() {

    return false;
}

@Override
protected float getBoltActionTime() {

    return 0.5f;
}

@Override
protected Vector2 getPosOffset() {
    return new Vector2(3,0);
}

@Override
protected Vector2 getShotStartingPosOffset() {
    return new Vector2(0,5);
}

@Override
public float getDamage() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public Vector2 getRecoilOffset() {
    return new Vector2(3,0);
}  } // cant seem to get this bracket to behave
```

I think a solution for this were EVERYONE would be happy is if I used XML to load the properties instead

Comment: "but would this create problems down the line?" depends on many things, for instance whether you call it many times - and how many is "many". Is `Vector2` mutable? If not, just store a value in a field, and return that from the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner Vector2 is mutable, yeah I was thinking of storing the vector on a field and call that field instead but I think having an abstract class checking if the field is null and filling it and then passing it would defeat the purpose of having the abstract classes in the first place. In practice it is not called many many times but for the sake of the question assume it is called every frame. Might be forced to ditch vector2s into 2 seperate methods instead. Or to load a big list of all parameters and make these abstract methods only run once? Edit: Maybe I could make an autoloader too

Comment: Your problem is entirely different. You are following bad text book examples regarding OOP design. Instead of creating a zoo of classes overriding methods to just return constants, create a single class having *fields* containing the actual values. Further, you are providing a perfect example of premature optimization. Just complete the software, check whether the performance is sufficient and if not, use  a profiling tool to check whether the actual performance problems are.

Comment: @Holger I don't really think it's a "bad text book example" the only reason of using abstract methods and overriding them with constants is to make many different objects that extend a main object. If this is a bad way to do things, how would I program a class "gun" that manages and draws and makes all the gun logic and then make many different types of guns, I know I could make a constructor but it would have many, many, MANY parameters. the example code I posted is only part of.... let me check... 21 parameters! I could also use setters but many of them are required to be functional

Comment: @Holger I mean, I can see why one shouldn't make objects like this but this way for this circumstance it seems alright and more readable. Again, many of these parameters must be set for the gun to be functional, some don't, creating a constructor with 21 parameters would be a nightmare atleast for me

Comment: If the number of constructors becomes large, the builder pattern would be your friend, but it seems that in your case, an embedded properties file would be more suitable for a maintainable application. This is directly connected with the question how to make a useful abstraction. The user level semantic is irrelevant here. Whatever you use for the visual representation, bitmap images, 3D models, etc, it does not depend on the type of objects. For the software, rendering a gun, a target, or a background object does not differ at all. They only have different *values*, not different behavior.

Comment: @Holger Hey thanks for letting me know about the builder pattern, I didn't know about it. I had an idea though, the main gun class is always called on the specific gun class constructor by calling super(), I could make it so that when the main gun class constructor is called, it puts everything on fields on the main gun class from these abstract methods so they would only be called/created once and then use the fields for the logic itself. Would fix the new Vector2() problem for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your design correctly, you have a base class `GunBase` like this:

```
public abstract class GunBase
{
    public abstract String getImageFileName();
}
```

and implementations of that like this:

```
public final class Winchester extends GunBase
{
    @Override
    public final String getImageFileName() { return "Winchester.png"; }
}
```

If `GunBase` really contains only those getter methods, it should not be a *class* at all, but an *interface*.

If `GunBase` really provides functionality that is only parameterised by the return values of those getters, those getters should not be overridden at all; instead the base class should get attributes for the respective values:

```
public abstract class GunBase
{
    private final String m_ImageFileName;

    protected GunBase( final String imageFileName )
    {
        m_ImageFileName = imageFileName;
    }

    public final String getImageFileName() { return m_ImageFileName; }
}
```

A derived class would then look like this:

```
public final class Winchester extends GunBase
{
    public Winchester() 
    { 
        super( "Winchester.png" ); 
    }
}
```

Confessed, the parameter list for the protected constructor can get inconveniently long in this case, but this can be solved by using a map with all the values instead of discreet arguments.

Now only those methods remain abstract that describe a behaviour that is different for each gun (*really* different, not only a different value for a parameter).

But if a gun is in fact nothing else than a collection of values, you should think about why you designed your guns as a class tree, and not as a collection of a class `Gun` where each instance describes one weapon type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you are right, I should check more about interfaces and or make guns be created with a hashmap of values or something.

Answer (score 3):

This design contradicts one of the main OOP principles - [Tell-Don't-Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html#:%7E:text=Tell%2DDon%27t%2DAsk,an%20object%20what%20to%20do.). I.e. instead of having code like this:

```
abstract class Gun {
    
    public void fire() {
        if (isBolt()) {
           // do bolt specifics
        } else if (isArrow()) {
           // do arrow specifics
        } else if (...)
    }
}
```

you need to have code like this:

```
abstract class Gun {
    abstract void fire();
}

class Bow extends Gun {
    public void fire() {
        // fire an arrow
    }
}

class CrossBow extends Gun {
    public void fire() {
        // fire a bolt
    }
}
```

Your primary motivation defined in the question is a [GoF Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), but note that it defines a skeleton for the **whole processing** and shouldn't have anything like `if (type == "laser")` mixins.

Generally common super-class should have only properties (fields/methods) which are truly common for all sub-classes. If you have there, say, `boltActionTime` which is used only by a single sub-class, that is wrong (and of course base class should know anything about sub-classes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but alas I don't think you get what I was trying to do on gun class, the gun class in my project would and does handle a fire method, the first code snippet is bad and I agree with you but the second can be reduced to a single fire method in the main gun class, in the sense that Bow and Crossbow shoot an arrow, I don't ask if it's a bolt or an arrow, I just ask for a projectile and whatever it is, is used and shot. Check my update I will show you a snippet of my "gun class"

Comment: Done, I've updated it, I think creating hundreds of fire methods for every single gun is madness ngl when they do the same thing everytime, for melee for example I have another class seperate from Firearm that does VERY different logic

Answer (score 3):

What I'm wondering is whether you're mixing up classes and instances. Let's say you have an AK-47. Regardless of how many AK-47s you have, they will all look and behave the same, except perhaps for some specialisations such as visors or different stocks.

This means that they are essentially constants. An AK-47 is not going to be a double-barrelled shotgun, after all. It's not going to fire arrows either.

What you need to do is see what is essentially different *in terms of logic* between your different guns. Because the rest are all properties. If there are only properties, you don't need subclasses.

If you're going to need more than one AK-47, you would simply have a list, all pointing to the same AK-47 instance.

Even if you have different behaviour, in the sense that it requires distinct code, between guns, chances are you can lump them into groups: shotguns, flintlock, fully automatic, etc. In that case, you only need classes for the differing behaviour.

It's the same with pets. You can have dogs, cats, hamsters, fish, whatever. But whether you have a British shorthair, a Persian, a Bengal or an ordinary street cat, they all say "meow" and have pointy ears. You don't need to implement "meow" for every breed of cat.

Answer (score 1):

Following is mini version of your implementation with my suggestion:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception{
        Firearm gun = new Winchester();
        gun.fire();
        
        gun = new HenryRifle();
        gun.fire();
    }

}

class Winchester extends Firearm {
    //as you are hard coding the values, 
    //the property belongs to the class Winchester 
    private static Vector2 wVec = new Vector2(1,2);
    
    public Winchester() {
        //if wVec was not static then use
        //super.posOffset = wVec;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Vector2 getPosOffset() {
        return wVec;
    }
}

class HenryRifle extends Firearm {
    private static Vector2 hVec = new Vector2(3,0);
    @Override
    protected Vector2 getPosOffset() {
        return hVec;
    }
}

abstract class Firearm {
    Vector2 posOffset;
    protected abstract Vector2 getPosOffset();
    protected Firearm() {
        this.posOffset = getPosOffset();
    }

    //all sub classes will inherit fire method 
    //no need to override it everywhere
    public void fire() {
        System.out.println("bang bang at " + posOffset);
    }
}

record Vector2(int x, int y) {}
```

This outputs:

```
bang bang at Vector2[x=1, y=2]
bang bang at Vector2[x=3, y=0]
```

I think you need to separate logic from too much data:
Create something like **GunProps.getProperty("manchester", "posOffset")** to feed logic in the Firearm class. And if a gun has different behavior then override that method in sub class.
Performance hit won't be much for calling one method and retrieving data from Map of Maps.

Answer (score 1):

Rumtime efficiency and abstraction/design are two different things. Like you said:

> I could load a list and put everything there neatly without creating additional objects...

That brings runtime efficiency, however it doesn't make abstract class useless because there could also be various of strategies.

For example, when a bullet is fired, how do you calculate its trajectory? You can think of so many different strategies to make it funnier, and you will create more and more over time. If you mix these strategies in one method for all kind of guns, it will be hard to extend. The best option is to seperate them, to create abstraction.